# How to search in list of maps by key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of map and I want to get the map of specific key
for example :
video of letter a

```
List<Map<String, String>> letters = const [
  {
    'letter': 'a',
    'name' : 'ddd',
    'video' : 'ss',

  },
  {
    'letter': 'b',
    'name' : 'ddd',
    'video' : 'ss',

  },
  {
    'letter': 'c,
    'name' : 'ddd',
    'video' : 'ss',

  },
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can use .where method like this

```
List listWithVideo = letters.where((element) => element['letter'] == 'a').toList();
```

Now here you will get list of maps where you will find your letter a.

If you want to get only one map or the first map that has the same, you can also use firstWhere method.

Comment: what is o in o['letter'] ?

Comment: my bad @Terminator. had a typo

Answer (score 1):

I am also beginner,but here is my effort

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, String>> letters = const [
  {
    'letter': 'a',
    'name': 'ddd',
    'video': 'ss',

  }
  ,
{
  'letter': 'b',
  'name' : 'ddd',
  'video' : 'ss',

  },
  {
  'letter': 'c',
  'name' : 'ddd',
  'video' : 'ss',

  },
  ];



  Map<String,dynamic> lst=letters.firstWhere((element) {

    return element['letter']=='a';
  });

  print(lst['video']);



}
```

its showing correct output

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> getAMap() {
    var list = letters.where((element) => element["letter"] == "a").toList();
    return list.isNotEmpty ? list.first : {};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this , so i can use the index and get the data that i want from the map

```
int search (String letter){
  int index=0;
  for ( var i=0 ; i<list.length;i++ )
  {
    if (list[i]['letter']==letter){
      index=i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Comment: there is a simple solution, do you want it?

Comment: sure , I want it